Was Cain a Murderer?
Is Cain a murderer or merely a manslaughterer? I ask because it would appear that his punishment is consistent with that of a manslaughterer based upon Numbers 35. He was 1. Exiled and 2. Protected from being killed for his crime. In the Mosaic Law the Cities of Refuge serve both as a place of exile AND as a safe-haven from the avenger of blood.
On the other hand, whether we consider the Noahide or Mosaic Covenants, the punishment for murder is death.
Of course, the Mosaic Law as such had not been given at this point in the narrative - but if we assume that God’s justice is consistent then there shouldn’t be a problem with using the Mosaic Law to analyze this situation.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64410

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/131747/. See B'reishis Rabba 22:12: "רַבִּי נְחֶמְיָה אָמַר לֹא כְּדִינָן שֶׁל רוֹצְחָנִין דִּינוֹ שֶׁל קַיִן, קַיִן הָרַג וְלֹא הָיָה לוֹ מִמִּי לִלְמֹד, מִכָּאן וָאֵילָךְ כָּל הוֹרֵג קַיִן יֵהָרֵג" ("Rabbi Nechemya said: The punishment of Cain was not like that for other murderers. Cain killed without any cautionary precedent from which to learn. From then and onwards, Cain served as the cautionary precedent for other would-be murderers: 'Therefore anyone who kills Cain [will be killed]' (Gen. 4:14)").

If one would like to push the Ir Miklat analogy, Cain's punishment was that of שוגג קרוב למזיד, which is not in a city of refuge, but rather a constant wandering from place to place (i.e. constant running avay from goel hadam).

One consideration (from Yefeh Toar, Bereishis Rabbah 22:12) is that Cain simply didn't know that certain kinds of blows or injuries can kill a person; Abel was, after all, the first human being to die. So that does indeed reduce Cain's culpability to manslaughter.
There is also the point (in the Midrash, ibid. 22:13) that Cain repented. To be sure, that doesn't help when it comes to a human court punishing the criminal, but one reason for that is because they can't possibly know whether his repentance is sincere. But G-d knows, and since Cain's punishment was coming directly from Him, there could be room for leniency.
